# Android Listview -How to set listview in getview() override. Listview taking parent layout instead of listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have posted this earlier in forums but I guess I am not clear . I have a sidebar Listview and a main panel which contains my controls. I want to highlight the active item in `listview` in `oncreate()` as a new activity is launched for each click in sidebar. Here is my `listview` layout for reference-[image]

But I am writing my `GetView() override` wrong ,so my layout is ending up like this.
[image]

This is my Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewMenuA2"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            >

        </TextView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time To Gather Knapsacks
                "
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Number of KnapSacks"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/numberKnapSack"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start Time"
                android:id="@+id/A2Stbutton"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:id="@+id/A2textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numberKnapSack"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="End Time"
                android:id="@+id/A2Stopbutton2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:onClick="SetEndTime"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:id="@+id/A2textView3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="212dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/A2button3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/A2button3"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/A2button3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next"
                android:id="@+id/A2button3"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:onClick="NextActivity"
                android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/A2Stopbutton2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Take Picture"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/A2button3"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my CustomAdapter

```
package com.example.listviewandroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by  on 10/2/13.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mycontext;
    ArrayList<String> contactsList;
    LayoutInflater minflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.mycontext=context;
        contactsList=list;
        minflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
@Override
    public int getCount()
{
    return contactsList.size();
}


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return contactsList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


@Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
     LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) mycontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2,parent,false);

    if (convertView !=null)
    {
        if (position ==1)
        {
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
    }
    return  view;
}

}
```

This is my Activity Code

```
package com.example.listviewandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.format.Time;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by on 9/26/13.
 */
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;
    static final String A2STE="";
    static final String A2STM="";
    static final String  Knapsacks="";
     @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String > list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Test");
        list.add("Test");list.add("Test");list.add("Test");list.add("Test");list.add("Test");


      CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,list);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {



                switch( position )
                {
                    case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(Activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);

                        break;

                    case 2:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity1);

                        break;
                    case 3:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity4.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity2);

                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity5.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity3);

                        break;
                    case 5:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity6.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity4);

                        break;

                }
            /*    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
*/
            }

        });
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        TextView textview2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView2);
        textview2.setText(now.hour+" : "+now.minute);

        if (savedInstanceState !=null)
        {
            restoreState(savedInstanceState);

        }

        this.listView.setSelector(R.drawable.selector_resource);
    }



    private void restoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberKnapSack);

        editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(Knapsacks));

        TextView startime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView2);

        startime.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(A2STE));

        TextView endtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView3);

        endtime.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(A2STM));



    }





    public void SetEndTime(View view) {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        TextView textview3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView3);
        textview3.setText(now.hour+" : "+now.minute);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberKnapSack);
        outState.putString(Knapsacks,editText.getText().toString());

        TextView startime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView2);
        outState.putString(A2STE,startime.getText().toString());

        TextView endtime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.A2textView3);
        outState.putString(A2STM,endtime.getText().toString());




    }

    public void NextActivity(View view) {
        Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
        startActivity(newActivity1);
        this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }

}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: you should be using fragments here and not one layout with everything thrown in, its a lot easier to manage and read

Comment: @tyczj i understand fragments are easy but is there anyway i can make it work with my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your problem

in your activity you do this

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
```

which is fine but in your `getView` of your `adapter` you also do this

```
View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2,parent,false);
```

so you are inflating the same layout again, clearly you dont want that

Comment: I understand i was inflating my activity layout again but am trying to understand how to  inflate just listview with background of list set to blue.

Comment: in your get view you inflate the row of your listview so whatever your layout of a row is in a listview is what you should be inflating

Comment: How can i inflate listview ?I am only able to inflate layouts .

Comment: you dont inflate a listview you inflate views for the listview. you populate a listview, if you dont know how to do that look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews